# Is it possible to make an app with .NET-Core for Windows Mobile 6.5?

Tags: .net, .net-core, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

I've been researching for a couple hours but my question needs proffessional knowledge.
I would love to know whether it is possible to write a program with .NET-Core for the Windows Mobile 6.5 operating system?

If it's not possible I will have to use the .NET Compact-Framework.

Thank you very much in advance c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Mobile is a pretty old OS, not supported anymore (2008?). There is no .Net Core runtime for such devices. The runtime would have to be ported, and I don't think there is enough traction to make it happen.